# mysql stored procedure column error

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

I receive the following error. But I havent typed count in my stored procedure so why is it giving this error?

```
  CALL updateproposalStatus(1,5)    Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

**STORED PROCEDURE:**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `updateProposalStatus`(IN decision INT, IN x INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE adv_id varchar(30);
DECLARE std_id varchar(30);
DECLARE topic varchar(255);

select
 a.id INTO adv_id
 from
 rp_proposal p
 inner join rp_adviser a on p.rp_adviser_id = a.id
 where p.proposal_id=x;

 select
 s.id INTO std_id
 from
 rp_proposal p
 inner join rp_student s on p.rp_student_id = s.id
 where p.proposal_id=x;

 select
 p.title INTO topic
 from
 rp_proposal p
 where p.proposal_id=x;

UPDATE rp_proposal_status
SET state_rp_controller =decision
WHERE rp_proposal_id = x;

IF decision = 1 THEN
INSERT INTO rp_indpstudy VALUES (topic,adv_id,std_id);
END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the column-count (number of columns) that it is complaining about, not about a column named `count`.

Most likely culprit is the  `insert` statement at the end - make sure that it is consistent with `rp_indpstudy`'s schema.

Comment: The insert statement is the culprit, because I left the primary key id field. but I set that to `AUTO INCREMENT` so why is it giving an error then.

Comment: Well I fixed the error by `INSERT INTO rp_indpstudy (name,rp_adviser_id,rp_student_id) VALUES (topic,adv_id,std_id);` before I didnt specify the column names